# Can I capture a user clicking on something like ALT A with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a web page and I have a button that calls a JavaScript. I would like to make it so that when the user presses a key combination such as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> then the same function gets called.

Also is it possible for jQuery to capture my user clicking the <kbd>Enter</kbd> or a function key like <kbd>F1</kbd>?

I have used simple jQuery but never for anything like this. Is it even possible?

Thanks

Comment: I added a question about clicking the Enter or F1 key to my question. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#target').keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == '13') {
        //Do something with the enter press
    }
}
```

Here is a list of all keyfunctions:

> http://www.webonweboff.com/tips/js/event_key_codes.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Check out the jQuery hotkeys plugin

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/hotkeys

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `keydown` and `keyup` jQuery functions to capture a single key press. The best way I can think to handle multiple simultaneous key presses (e.g. ALT + another key, or SHIFT + another key) is to listen for the control key presses and set a variable to true when that key press is detected, and to false when the key is released.

Then when any other key is pressed, you can check the value of your variable to see if a control key was held down at the same time.

The event handler for the `keydown` and `keyup` events provides a property which you can read to check for control keys: `event.altKey`, for example. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t8Xxz/) for a simple (and not perfect) example.